# Formula to eliminate all characters after a (optional) space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula which can eliminate spaces and useless characters after the space within a string.

My first instinct was to do the following: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))`

- It works for all cases that have a space
- But if a cell has no spaces in the cell my formula breaks.

I need one consistent formula that can work with hundreds of these two cases

What is a general formula that can handle cells with and without spaces?

I tried an IF statement as well, *but can't seem to figure out how to check if a space is in a string.*

Here is an example of my cells:[Example Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRIxf.png).

And the following are some values I am working with.

> AA
>   AA *+
>   C *-
>   A+
>   BBB

Comment: Some examples would be great. Are you saying that you want to eliminate all characters after the first space in a string, and leave the string as-is if there's no spaces?

Comment: That's correct, I want to eliminate everything after the space. But some of my cells will not have content that needs to be removed:

Comment: You could just add a space to the end of the string:  e.g. `=left(a1, find(" ", a1 & " ")-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the space you will want to use `Find()-1`.  To handle the no-space case use `IfError`

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),A1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This works on my small dataset I created. So pretty sure it will work tomorrow on the large data set I have. Only concern is if the content of my A1 cell is the function `=BDP(foo,baa)`, will the `Iferror` still handle it?

Comment: @AnthonyWorden `IfError` looks at the _value_ of its parameter, regardless of whether it's derived from cells entered as a constant or a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Writing formulas is like coding - you should be specifically testing for the issue you are handling, so would either suggest

Use Ron's formula - smart and simplest

```
==LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1 & " ")-1)
```

or using the initial string as is either of

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" ",A1)),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

or avoiding the error handling functions altogether

=`IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=LEN(A1),A1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))`